# Session.cookies.get_dict() return an empty dictionary

Tags: javascript, python

So I'm setting a cookie on every page with this javascript code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var pageStats = getCookie('PageStats');
  var currentPage = {
      "url": window.location.href,
      "render_time": $('.render_time').html(),
      "queries_number": $('.queries_number').html(),
      "queries_time": $('.queries_time').html()
    }
    document.cookie = "PageStats=" + JSON.stringify(currentPage) + ";path=/";
}, 1000);
```

Then I try to get it via my python script:

```
import requests
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:800/')
    print(response.cookies.get_dict())
```

This returns {}, though I can see all cookies via browser.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies that you are trying to get are from the session of `requests.Session()`, not the browser. The reason this happens is because that JavaScript is only executed when the HTML is rendered by your browser. As requests does not render the HTML, but just sends a simple HTTP request, those cookies are not being set. The only way that I could see this working is if you set the cookies on the server-side. 
Here's a simple example using Python 3's [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    r = make_response("Hello World")
    r.set_cookie("flask-cookie", "this is some data in a cookie")
    return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Or if you use NodeJS's [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/):

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.cookie("express-cookie", "this is some data in a cookie").send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(8080);
```